# Botão com 2 "href's" em php?

Tags: php, collapse

Olá! Acabei de criar minha conta no stack**overflow**. Tô sempre pesquisando coisas aqui e aprendendo mais sobre programação. Bom, como estou iniciando agora e entendo bem pouco de programação, comecei com um template pronto de Bootstrap ([esse aqui](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/sb-admin-2/)).

Eu preciso fazer com que um botão tenha 2 ações, no caso, 2 "href". Porque?
Estou fazendo (editando né, não sei programar ainda hehe) um site para documentação de algumas coisas da Empresa. Preciso que um botão do menu lateral (sidebar) tenha duas ações que seriam elas:

1° rolar a tela para baixo até o campo da sessão específica da documentação;
2° abra esse campo da sessão específica.

Como peguei um template pronto, estou usando uma função que achei bem bacana que é o "Collapse", então os menus ficam "escondidos" como se fosse um Spoiler, ocultando o conteúdo daquela sessão do documento.

Pra resumir bem, é rolar a tela até a sessão e abrir esse "spoiler" pra mostrar o conteúdo. Vou deixar aqui 2 links de "demonstração" de como funciona.

[Primeiro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCdYf.jpg) - [Segundo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrxNo.jpg)

Eu consigo fazer um botão abrir as sessões usando **href** e um **ID** que eu dou para a **div** onde está escrito "Sessão 1", "Sessão 2" e etc.
Exemplo:

Div:
`<div id="abrirsessao"></div>`

Rolar até a div:
`<a class="collapse-item" href="#abrirsessao" data-toggle="collapse">Abrir Sessão</a>`

---

Também consigo fazer a página rolar pra baixo usando o **href** + ID da **div**.
Exemplo:

Div:
`<div id="rolarsessao"></div>`

A:
`<a class="collapse-item" href="#rolarsessao">Rolar até a sessão</a>`

Acredito que o problema aconteça porque existe uma div dentro da outra.
Se eu conseguir atribuir 2 "href's", um para o **#rolarsessao** e outro para o **#abrirsessao** acredito que funcionaria.

Desde já agradeço quem puder ajudar (ou tentar) :D

Comment: Recomendo jQuery (embora a linguagem não faça parte das tags) utilizando onclick com show/hide.

Comment: Tem algum tutorial que possa me indicar sobre isso? Estou começando em programação e não tenho muita noção.

Answer (score 0):

Abaixo segue um exemplo, é só adequar ao seu código.

Não usei show/hide mas slideToggle.

Não esquecer de colocar o jQuery nas tags .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('h2.accor1').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('div.accor1a').slideToggle("slow");
 });
  $('h2.accor2').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('div.accor2a').slideToggle("slow");
 });
});
```

```css
h2.accordion{ cursor: pointer; }
div.accordion{ display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="exemplo">
 <h2 class="accordion accor1">Título1</h2>
 <div class="accordion accor1a">
  <p> texto de descrição </p>
 </div>
  <h2 class="accordion accor2">Título2</h2>
 <div class="accordion accor2a">
  <p> texto de descrição </p>
 </div>
</div>
```